# How to safely kill a python loop?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, stream

I've created a python program to stream data from elasticsearch into an S3 bucket. Because it will be a continuous stream I would like to implement a way to kill the program after it finishes a full loop.

I have something like:

```
While True:
timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
sizeMb = 0

Open Scroll with filter

    While (scroll_size > 0):
        Start scrolling through pages and add docs to the data variable
        
        if (processTime > 60s or size of data compressed > 3Mb):
            break

    Write data to file in S3 bucket
```

Is there a way to import and reimport another file and check the variable under the `While True:` clause or even better at the end of the script and if it is set to True then break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I've answered my own question in the process. I am using Python 3.7
I've created a file called killProcess.py and have a simple `kill = false` within. I've added to imports
`import killProcess, importlib`
and at the bottom of the loop I've added

```
While True:
   #code within loop

   importlib.reload(killProcess)
   if killProcess.kill:
       break
```

and does the trick